# Jquery .load() specific fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load specific page content and target it by ID.

```
let element = $('#element-id');
element.load('link #element-id > *');
```

So far, so good, everything is working fine.

The problem is that the element is a kind of widget, so if there is more than one element on the page, the content is doubled, tripled and so on.

How can I use `load()` to load specific page fragments only once?

Here is my HTML structure of `element-id`:

```
<div id="element-id">
    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="pagination">
        pagination goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In that case you need to make your selector more specific. Without seeing the HTML structure, we can't offer any more useful assistance

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan edited my question, provided HTML structure.

Comment: `D. Dimitrov` You need to empty the load target before load like **$('load-area').html('')** after that load your content functionality.

Comment: Neither if I empty it, the content is doubled or tripled because of the next page(link) there is more than one `element-id`.

Comment: That's an issue in itself then, as `id` need to be unique within a page

Answer (score 0):

I think your question miss some info in order to be fully understand. From what you wrote, you are trying to load an HTML fragment and put it into one specific element on the page. This element should be ***uniquely*** determined by its (unique) id tag. Just as an example, let's say we have those HTML elements on the page:

```
<div id="widget-1"></div>
<div id="widget-2"></div>
...
<div id="widget-n"></div>
```

In order to load contents only into one specific div, let's say the div identified by the "widget-2" id, you should do something like this:

```
jQuery( '#widget-2' ).load( 'url-to-your-content.html' );
```

Hope this will help to clarify the question, also give a look at: https://api.jquery.com/load/